# R Convert vector of epochs to POSIXct

Tags: r, dplyr

R noob question: I have a dataframe called `train` with an integer column called `some_time` containing times as epochs:

```
> library(dplyr)
> train[,"some_time"]
# A tibble: 486,048 x 1
    some_time
        <int>
1  1463497837
2  1461357640
3  1463499639
4  1463182983
5  1461855019
6  1459927021
7  1460230930
8  1462282973
9  1462888545
10 1462888549
# ... with 486,038 more rows
```

When I try to convert these times to POSIXct, I get an error:

```
> as.POSIXct(train[, "some_time"], origin = "1970-1-1", tz = "GMT")
as.POSIXct(train[,"some_time"], origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
Error in as.POSIXct.default(train[, "some_time"], origin = "1970-01-01",  : 
  do not know how to convert 'train[, "some_time"]' to class "POSIXct"
```

I suspect this has something to do with dplyr and tibble, as it is returning a dataframe instead of a vector - for example, all of the following return the same column tibble as shown above, instead of the first number value:

```
train[, "some_time"][1]
train[, "some_time"][1][1]
as.vector(train[,"some_time"])[1]
c(train[,"some_time"])[1]
```

How do I get the as.POSIXct to correctly convert the times as a vector?

Comment: The linked question may not seem like a duplicate, but it's the same problem conceptually. The answer there should be applied here. Long story short, use `train[["some_time"]]` or `train$some_time`

Comment: Yes, you are right - and I actually made some progress by using `train[["some_time"]]`, or alternatively loading train in using `as.data.frame(read.csv...)`, to avoid dplyr changing its structure - I am now stuck at a later stage of my problem  - posted as a separate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314145/how-to-split-epochs-into-year-month-etc